# Recurring payment in paypal integration with codeigniter is not working

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, recurring

Hello I am new to PayPal integration. I am using the Express checkout of PayPal for payment.
I wrote the code use `SetExpressCheckout` method then `GetExpressCheckout` method and then use `DoExpressCheckout` method. After `DoExpressCheckout` I am calling the `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` for recurring payment. Code as follows-

```
$recurringdata = array(
                        'TOKEN' => $token,//token id

                        'PayerID' => $payerid,//payer id

                        'PROFILESTARTDATE' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time),

                        'DESC' => "description",

                        'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Day',

                        'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => 1,

                        'AMT' =>$checkoutDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'],

                        'TRIALBILLINGPERIOD'=>'Day',

                        'TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY'=>1,

                        'TRIALAMT'=> 0,

                        'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',

                        'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',

                        'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS' =>3
                     );

  $responserecurring = $paypal->request('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $recurringdata);
```

This code creates the profile but I can not see that any recurring payment is done. I am not getting what actually happens. Is am I missing to pass any parameter in request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i am missing the one parameter i.e. 'TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES'. This parameter is an optional so i am not used this. So my trail period goes in infinite state. So payment is not deducting from account.I pass the data like as_

$recurringdata = array(
                        'TOKEN' => $token,//token id

```
                    'PayerID' => $payerid,//payer id

                    'PROFILESTARTDATE' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time),

                    'DESC' => "description",

                    'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Day',

                    'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => 1,

                    'AMT' =>$checkoutDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'],

                    'TRIALBILLINGPERIOD'=>'Day',

                    'TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY'=>1,

                    'TRIALAMT'=> 0,

                    'TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES' => 1,

                    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',

                    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',

                    'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS' =>3
                 );
```

$responserecurring = $paypal->request('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $recurringdata);